# What is Error:screenSize" />?

Tags: android-studio, screen-size

I am getting this error on installing and launching the app, but it does not effect working of my app. But still why am I getting this :

> Error:screenSize" />

[image: This is the error]

Comment: getting same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error but project run successfully

the problem occurred whenever I collapse tag

for example

```
 <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation" />
```

then i did like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"></activity>
```

now error disappears and Android Studio gives me warning "XML tag has empty body"

***No exact solution found***

Tested on

> Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: whenever i use facebook ads this happens fb native ads

Comment: in my case, it happens in everytime with close tag

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt  actually i could not found any strong solution rather than this

Answer (score 0):

In my case **above solution didn't worked** , so i debugged a bit and found out that facebook SDK didn't mention about any manifest changes in their documentation , but somewhere i found this on blog

## Solution

Add/update below code in your manifest( if using Facebook Ads SDK ):

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Apparently the conclusion is you **maybe missing activity declaration in manifest** of some sorts, Hope this post will help someone in future.

## Tip:

Open your Manifest and switch to **merged manifest** tab and recheck it that it is merged okay